# Android Studio - Google WebDriver

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver

I tried my best to use "Google WebDriver" tool that could be downloaded SDK manager. All I could really find was this: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/10/introducing-android-webdriver.html
Post from 2011, unsurprisingly code doesn't work and uses deprecated classes.

So here are my questions:

1. Is there any example code that would show me how to do anything using this tool?
2. Should I give up this Android Studio plugin and get selendroid instead? (http://selendroid.io/setup.html)

The best I could do is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        simpleGoogleTest();
    }

    private void simpleGoogleTest() {
        WebDriver driver = new AndroidWebDriver(this); // app crashes here

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised Google WebDriver is tool included in the Android SDK.  WebDriver has moved on a lot since 2011.  A lot of what you are trying to do can now be achieved with [Appium](http://appium.io) and [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/).

Comment: So, what you're trying to say is that this tool from Android SDK is totally obsolete? Okay, will look for something else. However, what I am trying to achieve is something not related to tests. AFAIK, selenium can be used to much more than tests. I just need a tool with html parser, able to click, write, execute js etc. Can Appium do this? Because I can't understand how ChromeDriver might be able to help me.

Comment: I'm afraid so- I think the tool is at version 2.0 and Chrome has moved on a lot since 2011! Appium does the difficult stuff with ChromeDriver, so all you need to do is start Appium and include the Appium java client bindings.  I would recommend looking at the appium site, and join their forum.